# Exporting the Organizational Chart

Tags: my-site, export, organization-browser

Is there a way to export the organizational chart located in the mysites to excel or another program?

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to find a way to export the organizational chart straight from SharePoint 2010, but I did find a free tool that will pull the users from Active Directory and create an org chart in Visio.

PowerGui connects to Active Directory and with the installation of the org chart powerpack you can easily view the chart in Visio 2007 or later.

Check it out!

http://poshoholic.com/2009/06/27/create-your-own-org-chart-from-ad-with-powergui/

Comment: PowerGUI has been swallowed up in corporate acquisitions. In 2015 it was still available in [a few places](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2015/01/30/download-links-for-powergui-and-qad-cmdlets/) but might be gone completely now.